# Scala: how to make Slick store a custom class object?

Tags: class, scala, orm, slick

I want to store something with my defined class:

```
case class Contact(var name: String, var phone: Option[String],  val email: String)

object Contacts extends Table[Contact]("CONTACTS") {
  def email = column[String]("email", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def phone = column[String]("phone", O.Nullable)

  def * =  name ~ phone ~ email <> (Contact.apply _, Contact.unapply _)
}
```

The error is:

```
[error]  cannot be applied to ((String, Option[String], String) =>
models.Contact, models.Contact => Option[(String, Option[String],
String)]) [error]   def * =  name ~ phone ~ email <> (Contact.apply _,
Contact.unapply _)
```

I understand that if I change `Table[Contact]` to `Table[(String, String, String)]`, it would work. But I just want to make `Contact` as a table and the Contact class can server for another class like `Contact` can server the `User` class.

How should I implement this?

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't that your phone column is String-typed, while the phone field is Option[String]-typed? On an unrelated note, do you really mean to use mutable fields in your case class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile error is simply a result of the type mismatch between the phone field (`Option[String]`) and the phone column (`String`).

As @cvogt suggested, you can fix the mismatch by using an `Option` for the phone column:

```
def phone = column[Option[String]]("phone")
```

Alternatively, you can change the `*` method so that it will correctly convert between the case class's `Option` field and the table's `Nullable` column:

```
def * =  name ~ phone.? ~ email <> (Contact, Contact.unapply _)
```

Comment: can you tell me why if I delete " <> (Contact.apply _, Contact.unapply _)" there is also error?

Comment: Yes. Roughly, the type of the `*` method has to correspond to the type of the `Table`. If you remove that part, the type corresponds to `(String, Option[String], String)`. By providing the `<>` part, you're expressing how to convert between that type and the `Contact` type: `Contact.apply` converts a `(String, Option[String], String)` to a `Contact`, while `Contact.unapply` converts a `Contact` to a `(String, Option[String], String)`.

Comment: While this answer compiles and does the right thing in this case, it is not the suggested way to do it. O.Nullable should not be used. Use an Option type instead.

Comment: @cvogt Agreed. Using an Option would express the intent better.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Option type instead of O.Nullable for phone:

```
def phone = column[Option[String]]("phone")
```